# Show every container element with for_each function

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, foreach

I like to understand more about templates. I tried to write my own function, that shows every container element.

```
void show_element(int i){
std::cout << i << endl;
}

int main(){

int dataarr[5]={1,4,66,88,9};
vector<int> data(&daten[0],&daten[0]+5);

std::for_each(data.begin(),data.end(),show_element) 

...
```

My show_element function isn't generic yet. How do i have to write it, so that i can use it for different container-types?

```
template <typename T>
using type = typename T::value_type;
void show_element(type i){ //type i must be sthg like *data.begin()
std::cout << i << endl;
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a function it is more flexible to use a class. In this case you can  pass additional arguments to the functional object.

For example you could specify a stream where you are going to output the elements or a separator that will separate the elements in the stream.

The class can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class show_elements
{
public:
    show_elements( const std::string &separator = " ", std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
        : separator( separator ), os( os ) {}
    std::ostream & operator ()( const T &value ) const
    {
        return os << value << separator;
    }
protected:
    std::string separator;
    std::ostream &os;
};    

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 4, 66, 88, 9 };    
    std::vector<int> v( arr, arr + sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ) );

    std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), show_elements<int>() );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 4 66 88 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
template <typename T>
void show_element(T const &i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
```

`for_each` applies the given function (e.g., show_element) on the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range [first, last), in order. So you don't need to take the value_type of the container.

Also in c++14 and above you could define a generic lambda:

```
auto show_element = [](auto const &i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
```

and use it as:

```
int arr[] = {1, 4, 66, 88, 9};
std::vector<int> data(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));
std::for_each(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int), show_element);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b12ced9913cbfe0c)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to use range-based for loop.

```
for(auto& element : container) {
    cout<<element<<endl;
}
```